# Use data from one SQL-query to another

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store the values of the column 'following' in an array. However, I can't figure out what's wrong with this code.

```
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "user1");
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Followers WHERE user='$user'");
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] =  $row['following'];  
}
```

Comment: **Note:** sql injection is always important as you can easily do it with valid data yourself as well. **Note 2:** don't mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to use a jointure, which will be far more efficient :

```
Select * from message left join followers on followers.following=Messages.user where Follower.user=...
```

HTH
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will encounter problems if you forget to escape caracters like " ' " or "  "  " or even " \  ".

If I was you, I'd merge into a subquery this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE user IN 
               (SELECT * FROM Followers WHERE user='$user')"
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql );
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below 
`mysql_fetch_array($result)` with `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
session_start();
    $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "user1");
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];

    $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM Followers WHERE user='$user'");
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data[] =  $row['following'];  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out you ought to use a `prepared statement` to avoid nasty sql injection. As the only field that is being used is `follower` limit the columns returned ( makes it easier using below notation - notably `bind_result` )

```
session_start();

$data = array();
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "user1");
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

$sql='select `following` from `followers` where user=?';
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$user);
    $res=$stmt->execute();

    if( $res ){
        $stmt->bind_result($follower);
        while( $stmt->fetch() ){
            $data[]=$follower;
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
$db->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 errors in code:
1.mysql_query() is deprecated and may give error so use mysqli_query() which expects 2 paramter connection and query. 
2.Your query is not receiving user variable value since its a string.
3.Your row is not an associative array for which you can get following value so use mysqli_fetch_assoc() instead.

You can use the following code:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "user1");
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM followers WHERE user='".$user."'");
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[]=$row['following']; 
}
```